# setting property of js map/object

Tags: javascript, object, dictionary

Can i use

```
myWidget.errorLableMap.key ="errormsg";
```

insted of following to set property of a js object/map.

```
myWidget.errorLableMap["key"] ="errormsg";
```

Comment: yes, i think it works, but wanted to confirm

Comment: yes you can the square brackets are simply alternative syntax for the dot notation. However make sure that you have constructed your myWidget object and nested all your objects proplery inside that one, otherwise it won't work.

Comment: am trying to use the object as a map, so want to set/get property that way

Answer (score 1):

You can do both - they are equal ways of assigning a property value. The difference is - using [] you can work with properties that are not valid variable names in javascript, e.g. you can do:

```
myWidget.errorLableMap["key 1"] = "something"
```

but obviously following will not work:

```
myWidget.errorLableMap.key 1 = "something"
```

Comment: Additionally, the [] form is useful if the name of the property is stored in a variable.  e.g. var fieldName = "somekey"; myWidget.errorLabelMap[fieldName]